# Copying from a valid mapped network drive

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I'm writing a batch file to copy files from a mapped network drive (Z:) to the local disk (C:).

The issue is that sometimes the mapped network drive has taken the letter Z, sometimes Y, or any other letter (though it is mapped to the same thing).

How will I say in my batch file to copy from the valid letter (network drive)?
As of now my script is as follows:
`copy Z:\*.log C:\Fiblogs`

But at times the mapped netowrk drive can be Y:\ or W:\ etc.  How can I account for this in my script?

Answer (score 2):

You do not - the scenario is terrible. If that is a mapped drive, it should be centrally controlled and set up. By login scripts, for examlple.

If you have a ton, maybe just use ONE and use DFS to mape a hierarchiy of folders to different locations.

But in general, a lot of things will break when mapped drives "move around" nd people have links etc. that point to other locations.

Yes, you can theoretically find out where a mapped drive points, then look up which drive letter to use based on that - but that is a LOT of work to work around what is fundamentally a system administrator failure to provide a stable environment.

Comment: thnx Tom for the clarifications. For the info, there's only 1 network drive. How do we use the login script? Or any other suggestion.

Comment: Ah, you DO Know that "novice questions" are off topic here? "How do I use a login script" IS a novice question. A book about basic system administration can help you learn the trade.

Answer (score 0):

Right way in your batch file:

`copy \\serverFQDN\share\*.log C:\Fiblogs`

OK way: In your batch file add/modify to:

`net use Z: /del`

`net use z: \\server\share`

`copy Z:\*.log C:\Fiblogs`

(and if you want to get technical, most will use `robocopy` and not just a `copy` command)